# Change JBoss tags to reflect the reality

Tags: discussion, tags

The JBoss tags are misleading.

JBoss is a brand, formerly a company. The company used to produce only an application server, an implementation of Java EE.

This is no longer true. JBoss is a brand, and under that brand, there are many things released:

- JBoss Application Server
- JBoss EAP
- JBoss Web Server
- JBoss Tools
- JBoss Developer Studio
- JBoss Forge
- JBoss ESB
- JBoss Web Services
- JBoss OSGI
- JBoss MicroContainer
- JBoss Modules
- JBoss Windup
- JBoss SOA Platform
- JBoss Portal

and more.

On StackOverflow, the tags used are:

- jboss-3.x
- jboss-4.0.x
- jboss-4.2.x
- jboss-eap-4.3.x
- [jboss5.x](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jboss5.x/info)
- jboss6.x
- jboss7.x
- jboss-eap-6

Besides being inconsistent in format, they don't reflect that there are for instance:
* JBoss Application Server 5.x
* JBoss EAP 5, which was based on JBoss AS 5.x, but is *significantly* different
* JBoss Application Server 7.x
* JBoss EAP 6, which was based on JBoss Application server 7.x
* JBoss EAP 7, which was based on Wildfly 10.x
* JBoss Web Server, which is based on Tomcat 7

Therefore, jboss6.x may be referring to both JBoss AS 6 or JBoss EAP 6, while these are *completely* different (whole AS project was rewritten for AS 7 / EAP 6).

I am suggesting hereby to reflect the reality in the tags, by renaming them to:

- jboss-3.x -> jboss-as-3.x
- jboss-4.0.x -> jboss-as-4.0.x
- jboss-4.2.x -> jboss-as-4.2.x
- [jboss5.x](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jboss5.x/info) -> jboss-as-5.x
- jboss6.x -> jboss-as-6.x
- jboss7.x -> jboss-as-7.x
- jboss-eap-6 -> jboss-eap-6.x